# One set of tests for few projects with different parameters

Tags: jasmine, automated-tests, protractor, e2e-testing

i'm using Protractor and Jasmine and would like to organize my E2E test in the best way.

Example:

There is a set of the tests for check registration function (registration with right credentials, register as existed user, etc.).

I need to run those tests in three different projects. Tests are same, but credentials are different. For one project it could be 3 fields in the registration form, in another one - 6.

Now everything is organized in a very complicated way:

- each single test is made not as "it" but as a function
- there is a function which contains all tests (functions which test)
- there is a file with Describe function in each
- in that file there is one "it" which call the function which contains all tests
- there is test suite for each project

I believe that there is a practice how to organize everything in a right way, that each test was in own "it". So will be happy to see some links or advice.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's a broad question, i will redirect you to few links. You should probably be looking at page-object model of Protractor. It will help you simplify and set a standard to organise your tests in a way that is readable and easy to use. Here's the link to it as described by Protractor team.

- [page-object model](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/page-objects)

However if you want to know why do we need to use such a framework, there are many shortcomings to it, which can be solved by using such framework. A detailed explanation is here

- [shortcomings of protractor and how to overcome them](http://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/using-page-objects-overcome-protractors-shortcomings)

**EDIT:** Based on your comments i feel that you are trying make a unified file/function that can cater to all the suites that will be using it. In order to handle such things try adding a generalised function (to fill form fields in your case), export that function and then require it into your test suites. Here's a sample link to it -

- [Exports and require](http://ramonvictor.github.io/protractor/slides/#/33)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. Probably my question was not clear enough. I'm already using PageObjects and it's perfect. The problem is that now I put also expect functions in PageObjects, which I suppose is not correct.

Comment: @Radost_ I thought you were asking for a best way to organize your e2e tests using protractor. Let me know if that was not the thing you were looking out for.

Comment: Sorry, I pressed Enter too fast. I'm already using PageObjects and it's perfect. The problem is that now I put also expect functions in PageObjects, which I suppose is not correct. I also could make a perfect file with "Describe" and use PageObject in it. Also I have three projects which are similar but different (for one project I need to fill 3 fields in registration form, in another one - 6). I don't want to copy one big file with describe to three different suites. Somehow I want to do that I have one file, but run it for each project (with different input parametrs)

Comment: @Radost_ Updated answer to include exports and require feature which you can use to create one file to run it for each project.

Comment: thank you. That's exactly what I use. I put all tests in one so it's look now like `code` var allFunctionsToTestRegistration = function (inputs) {this.checkRegistrationIsSuccesfull = function(inputs) { expect(...).toBe(true)}`code` and than I call that function in my 'it'. So when I see the reports from the test I'm able to see only that one name from my single "it" and everything counts as a one test.

Comment: @Radost_ So did the answer help you to solve your problem? If so, please mark it as answer else provide an answer so that people searching for similar problem will be benefitted. Thanks :)